# How to shift subequations environment horizontally

Tags: amsmath, subequations

How can I shift a `subequations` environment to the left? `\hspace*{}` didn't work.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\begin{document}

\title{...}
\author{...}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}

%\hspace*{-2cm} 
\begin{subequations}
    %\hspace*{-2cm}
    \begin{align}[left = \empheqlbrace\,]
    %\hspace*{-2cm}
    &a,\\
    &b,
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `flalign` environment:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{...}
\author{...}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{subequations}
    %\hspace*{-2cm}
    \begin{flalign}[left = \empheqlbrace\,]
    a & = c + d, & \\
     b & = e + f,
    \end{flalign}
\end{subequations}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can place it inside a `\parbox` command as wide as you wish (but at least as needed for the equations)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\begin{document}

\title{...}
\author{...}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}

Test text here:

\parbox{0.14\textwidth}{\begin{subequations}
    %\hspace*{-2cm}
    \begin{align}[left = \empheqlbrace\,]
    %\hspace*{-2cm}
    &a,\\
    &b,
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]